# Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool failed with exit code 255

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7, xcode7-beta5

It happens in new Xcode7 beta:

```
CompileAssetCatalog /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaAd-ddgdnbxlpxipirebpndfmgrxspel/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/InstaAd.app InstaAd/Images.xcassets
    cd /Users/admin/Documents/git/InstaAdIOS/InstaAd
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaAd-ddgdnbxlpxipirebpndfmgrxspel/Build/Intermediates/InstaAd.build/Debug-iphoneos/InstaAd.build/assetcatalog_dependencies.txt --output-partial-info-plist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaAd-ddgdnbxlpxipirebpndfmgrxspel/Build/Intermediates/InstaAd.build/Debug-iphoneos/InstaAd.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --launch-image LaunchImage --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --filter-for-device-model iPhone7,2 --filter-for-device-os-version 8.4 --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --platform iphoneos --compile /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaAd-ddgdnbxlpxipirebpndfmgrxspel/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/InstaAd.app /Users/admin/Documents/git/InstaAdIOS/InstaAd/InstaAd/Images.xcassets

2015-08-10 14:25:53.366 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1054:10336] CoreUI(DEBUG): CSIGenerator using 'LZVN' Compression coreui version (358.000000)
2015-08-10 14:25:56.449 ibtoold[675:6100] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-08-10 14:25:56.450 ibtoold[675:6100] The agent crashed

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 179 - Device: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad1x - Runtime: iOS 9.0 (13A4325c) - DeviceType: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad1x


Thread 6 Crashed:: TDRenditionsDistiller._distill:
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010bc03f61 __CFBasicHashDrain + 353
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010bbf4a1c CFRelease + 300
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010bc03f42 __CFBasicHashDrain + 322
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010bbf4a1c CFRelease + 300
4   com.apple.ImageIO.framework     0x000000010d7f8028 modifyJPEG + 2859
5   com.apple.ImageIO.framework     0x000000010d6079b8 CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource + 576
6   com.apple.CoreThemeDefinition   0x000000010dbfcec9 -[TDSimpleArtworkRenditionSpec createCSIRepresentationWithCompression:colorSpaceID:document:] + 1690
7   com.apple.CoreThemeDefinition   0x000000010dc0555b -[TDRenditionsDistiller _distill:] + 609
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010b2c73ab __NSThread__start__ + 1198
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010d236268 _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010d2361e5 _pthread_start + 176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010d23441d thread_start + 13


Last command:
_ON_QUEUE_sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:

Backtrace of last command:
  0  0x00000001111c69f6 -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy _ON_QUEUE_sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  1  0x00000001111c68bb __74-[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  2  0x00007fff8c046c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff8c047e5e _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
  4  0x000000011007aabc DVTDispatchSync (in DVTFoundation)
  5  0x00000001111c67de -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x000000011aae2526 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x000000011aacda8b (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x000000011111dbf3 __84-[IBICAbstractPlatformAdapter compileSelectedItems:options:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9  0x000000011007abb0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 10  0x00007fff8c04b323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11  0x00007fff8c046c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff8c052cbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff8d58b3f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ (in CoreFoundation)
 14  0x00007fff8d54668f __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 15  0x00007fff8d545bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 16  0x00000001111912bc -[NSRunLoop(IBIDEFoundationRunLoopAdditions) ib_spinRunLoopInMode:whileBlockExecutesConcurrently:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17  0x00000001111914ba -[NSRunLoop(IBIDEFoundationRunLoopAdditions) ib_spinRunLoopInMode:waitingForSemaphore:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x000000010fde887a (in ibtoold)
 19  0x000000010fde9e30 (in ibtoold)
 20  0x000000010fdea2b0 (in ibtoold)
 21  0x000000010fdf7e6f (in ibtoold)
 22  0x000000010fdf8523 (in ibtoold)
 23  0x000000010fdf83fa (in ibtoold)
 24  0x000000010fde76c2 (in ibtoold)
 25  0x000000010fdf7a64 (in ibtoold)
 26  0x000000010fdf6cc9 (in ibtoold)
 27  0x00007fff8eb585c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
2015-08-10 14:25:56.451 ibtoold[675:6100] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d63803c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff980b976e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d637bd9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001111c5b55 -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy _errorByAddingAdditionalCrashInformationToError:orRaiseIfNeededOnFailure:shouldRaiseOnFailures:waitForCrashLog:] + 1632
    4   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001111c54cb -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy errorByAddingAdditionalCrashInformationToError:orRaiseIfNeededOnFailure:] + 98
    5   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001111c6a90 -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy _ON_QUEUE_sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] + 227
    6   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001111c68bb __74-[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:]_block_invoke + 38
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c046c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c047e5e _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 57
    9   DVTFoundation                       0x000000011007aabc DVTDispatchSync + 62
    10  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001111c67de -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] + 393
    11  IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011aae2526 IBUISegmentConfiguration + 6975
    12  IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011aacda8b IBUIControlEventTypeToUIControlEventMask + 17323
    13  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000011111dbf3 __84-[IBICAbstractPlatformAdapter compileSelectedItems:options:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 230
    14  DVTFoundation                       0x000000011007abb0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 69
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c04b323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c046c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c052cbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 861
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d58b3f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d54668f __CFRunLoopRun + 2159
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d545bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    21  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001111912bc -[NSRunLoop(IBIDEFoundationRunLoopAdditions) ib_spinRunLoopInMode:whileBlockExecutesConcurrently:] + 500
    22  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001111914ba -[NSRunLoop(IBIDEFoundationRunLoopAdditions) ib_spinRunLoopInMode:waitingForSemaphore:] + 131
    23  ibtoold                             0x000000010fde887a ibtoold + 10362
    24  ibtoold                             0x000000010fde9e30 ibtoold + 15920
    25  ibtoold                             0x000000010fdea2b0 ibtoold + 17072
    26  ibtoold                             0x000000010fdf7e6f ibtoold + 73327
    27  ibtoold                             0x000000010fdf8523 ibtoold + 75043
    28  ibtoold                             0x000000010fdf83fa ibtoold + 74746
    29  ibtoold                             0x000000010fde76c2 ibtoold + 5826
    30  ibtoold                             0x000000010fdf7a64 ibtoold + 72292
    31  ibtoold                             0x000000010fdf6cc9 ibtoold + 68809
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8eb585c9 start + 1
    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool failed with exit code 255
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: The error was due to simulator, close your simulator if already opened, and run you app again it should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That happened because of JPG images in assets catalog, so I imported jpg images directly in the project, and now it works

Comment: Why would this be the case? Don't assets catalogs support JPGs?

Comment: it seems that it supports because you can even add jpg file to it, but than it started to crash in xcode beta. But when I removed all jpg from asset catalog, it started to work immidiatly

Comment: This is fixed in the GM seed release (available as of Sept. 9th). XC asset catalogs are working fine for me.

Comment: Yes the issue was due to other image types. It should only have PNGs

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Xcode V7b6 and JPG images in assets. Strangely this was working for some JPGs but not for others.

Then I've looked at the JPGs and their color profile, exif data and other meta stuff and indeed removing these data (via GraphicConverter) solved it for us and Xcode now builds fine.

Answer (score 1):

Pdf files in image assets will cause this error. I use png files for @1x @2x @3x images and Xcode works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened with me because the image name contained some unsupported characters (it was saved by Xcode as `c71a25e%2FÍcone-XPTO Imagem - 120x120.png`, even when placed in .xcassets).

Changing the image name solved this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you should uncheck de "alpha" option to export your png images to Xcode. That solve my problem.

Open "Preview" app - File - Export - Uncheck "alpha" option, then replace your old images in Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue as well, and replaced the XC Assets with plain .JPG files. Solved it for me.

However, I just installed the GM seed release of Xcode 7 and built with the XC assets catalog, and am no longer experiencing the error. So it appears to have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For all beta versions of Xcode you should go to **Preferences->Locations** and make sure that the **command line tools point to the right version** & that the Derived data and Archives point in a different folder that stable Xcode is

Answer (score 0):

Had this `actool` error building a simple Sticker Pack in Xcode 8 Beta 6.

Seems to be a [known error with animated stickers](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/169183) that should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Simple restart of Xcode fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

After all the suggestions also I couldn't get rid of this issue.
I was getting this issue after my OS was updated.

It worked for me when I started removing xcode caches.
Specifically removing 
`~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`
`~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode.ITunesSoftwareService`
`~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git`

I had to though remove and add needed simulators