# Build Failed: Asset Catalog Compile Error : failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, asset-catalog

I am getting this error while Archiving the project. Don't know why i am getting this error. Researched couldn't figure it out

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: once try by deleting derived data

Comment: How to delete it can you please explain me @AnjaliBhimani

Comment: open your xcode project then on topbar File -> workspace setting or project setting -> there one right arrow after derived data click on it and then delete it

Comment: no it din't work @AnjaliBhimani

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918339/command-applications-xcode-beta-app-contents-developer-usr-bin-actool-failed-wi    please check this link may be u get help from this

Comment: already done with that @AnjaliBhimani

Comment: ok i have one last solution : (close xocde and then run this command in terminal )http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found/32730393#32730393

Comment: din't work, anyway thanks for the help @AnjaliBhimani

Comment: @BhushanVU  no there is no such things app icons for some devices are empty but that has nothing to do with issue

Comment: @AnjaliBhimani thanks anjali and bambyland for helping me, Removing the alpha option by re exporting it in preview  did the trick for me.

Comment: But i need to know this, i had transparent images after removing they are looking white, do you have any idea is this a problem with the App store that it don take the images with the transparency or with Xcode 7.2